# Remove Factors with no data in facet grouping variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data :

```
data <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], 
                   group = rep(letters[1:2], each = 3), 
                   y = 1:6)

  x group y
1 a     a 1
2 b     a 2
3 c     a 3
4 d     b 4
5 e     b 5
6 f     b 6
```

And I would like to plot `y ~ x` and split into facets by groups with ggplot2.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(group ~ .)
```

[image]

The problem is that some tuples `(x; group)` don't exist in my data(for example there is no data for `x = a && group = b`) , but they are kept in the x-axis of both facets so I would like to remove them and then remove white spaces in the facets when factors are missing in respective groups.

I thought `scales = "free_x" or drop = TRUE` could do the trick but I couldn't manage to do it.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `facet_wrap` instead

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + 
     geom_col() + 
     facet_wrap(~group, scales = 'free', nrow = 2, strip.position = 'right')
```

also note `geom_col` as an alternative to using `identity`

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution. Wasn't aware about `geom_col` and `strip.position`  that came in recent versions.

Comment: `scale = 'free_x'` do the job for me!